# Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. Show that matrix multiplication, $x \to Ax$ , defines a homomorphism $\varphi$ : $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

To be 100% honest, I haven't started working on this problem because I have no idea where to start. usually I like to write what I have already tried and why it didn't work, but unfortunately I can't do that.

Comment: Homomorphism of what? Certainly a homomorphism of $\Bbb R$-vector spaces, also known as an $\Bbb R$-linear map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$\phi:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$ is a homomorphism if for every $x,y\in\Bbb{R}^n$, $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$.

You need to prove $A(x+y)=Ax+Ay$ for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 4):

Start by writing out explicitly what you need to show e.g. what does it mean that a map is a homomorphism?

Well, looking in the textbook says it means a the function between groups $\varphi: (G,\ast_G) \to (H,\ast_H)$ satisfies $\varphi(x \ast_G y)=\varphi(x) \ast_H \varphi(y)$.

Ask yourself: what is the group operation on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: The operation must be multiplication, since our problem deals with matrix multiplication.

Comment: @animorphlover3 The group operation on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is addition: $(\mathbb{R}^n, +)$.

Comment: @animorphlover3 Matrix multiplication defines the homomorphism between groups, but its not the group operation. In fact, there is no natural multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The natural operation on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is addition. The point is the *matrix multiplication* preserves *vector addition.*